# (AHK) Creating variable hotkeys that gets the key names from a 2 char file name of a script

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to make something for our employees to use so that they dont have to alter the script itself to define hotkeys. This may only work for hotkeys which can be defined by a single character, but that's fine, as there are so many combinations that can be made with them, and they can be very easy to remember. The script would look only at 2 character AHK files (or 6 if you must include the extension) in the working directory. And the variables it would search for could be defined with RegEx so for the first hotkey, it would look like ^. and then second would look like .(?=.) Once a match is found, it would simply launch that matched file. Has something like this been done before? It seems so simple but I can't seem to find anything on it.

Edit: Elliot brought this to my attention: http://autohotkey.com/board/topic/60630-easy-editmanage-hotkeyshotstrings-plugin-ahk-l/

It's a neat script manager, and very useful, but it's not what I'm looking for.

I dont not want an additional interface. I want to be able to change the hotkeys by using the filename.

Comment: http://autohotkey.com/board/topic/60630-easy-editmanage-hotkeyshotstrings-plugin-ahk-l/

Comment: Thanks Elliot but that's not what I'm looking for in this case. Please see my edit for more info.

Comment: Frankly, I don't really understand what  you want to do. Why do you need multiple files and why do they  have to be 2 chars long?? For managing different hotkey setups, I'd use iniread/iniwrite for configuration, maybe a gui for selection, and formostly the hotkey command http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Hotkey.htm which can assign hotkeys dynamically.

Comment: the files are script files. the file name has to be 2 characters long. i dont think you understand my question

Comment: True. Seems there is nothing we can do about it.

Comment: Why? isn't it possible for a script to create a list of 2 character filenames and load each set as a hotstring?

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid I can't decipher what it is you're looking for exactly.

Comment: It's a way to easily assign 2 letter/number hotkeys by changing the file name. There is a main script that looks at any script that has a file name that is 2 characters long and it loads those characters as a hotkey, and if the hotkey is pressed then it will execute that same script with the hotkey in the file name. Hopefully it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [answer of Forvin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34654159/4579407). Added the execution of the corresponding ahk script.

```
#Persistent
SetTimer, FindNewHotkeys, 2000
FindNewHotkeys:
    Loop, %A_ScriptDir%\*
    {
        RegExMatch(A_LoopFileName, "^(.)(.).ahk$", hk)

        If (hk)
        {
          Hotkey, ~%hk1% & ~%hk2%, HotkeyLabel
        }
    }
Return

HotkeyLabel:
  RegExMatch(A_ThisHotkey, "~(.) & ~(.)", hk)
  run, %hk1%%hk2%.ahk
Return
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you so much!

Comment: I thought I would give the bounty to you and mark the other one as the answer but I guess it makes more sense to give you both.

Answer (score 1):

```
#Persistent
SetTimer, FindNewHotkeys, 2000

FindNewHotkeys:
    Loop, %A_ScriptDir%\*
    {
        RegExMatch(A_LoopFileName, "^(.)(.).ahk$", hk)

        If (hk)
            Hotkey, ~%hk1% & ~%hk2%, HotkeyLabel
    }
Return

HotkeyLabel:
    MsgBox, A hotkey has been pressed!
Return
```

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work. I put the file in the same location as my .ahk file with the two letter filename (in this case I used GS). I started your script, tried the hotkeys and it did not display the messagebox

Comment: Then you must be doing soemthing wrong. Make sure the file doesn't have an extension. Also try to run the script as admin.

Comment: Oops. I didn't notice how the Regex was being used. I'm going to suggest a couple edits. I found another issue with the hotkeys lacking tildes in the front. Also, I am unsure how to launch the hotkey file.